# XCode AutoComplete current iPhone SDK, non-deprecated version?

Tags: iphone, xcode

Is there a way to configure XCode to autocomplete Cocoa methods with the most current, non-deprecated versions?

For instance

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello";
//xcode sets autocomplete to look like this
[myString writeToFile:arg1 atomically:arg2];
//however that gets a warning from the debugger
//the method is deprecated. the new method is:
[myString writeToFile:arg1 atomically:arg2 encoding:arg3 error:arg4];
```

I haven't mastered the memorization yet and I have been moving along by just using autocomplete and checking documentation when there is a problem.  I wonder why the default xcode configuration for the newest iPhone SDKs autocomplete with deprecated methods.  Can it be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When typing and you see autoComplete start to show the next part, hit the escape key, and you can see the available completions. Type one letter and see a bunch. Hit escape again to hide it.

But that doesn't really answer your question on deprecated methods...